# 64 bit Simulink does not generate a 64 bit DLL

Tags: dll, simulink

I made a simple model in simulink that just multiplies the signal by 2 and sends the output. When I build the model, I think Simulink is generating a 32 bit DLL. The application I am using it in is 64 bit. When I use the DLL in the application, I get the following error:

" Could not load file or assembly 'LOCATION OF DLL' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest. "

From an search online, I felt the issue was that the DLL generated was 32 bit and I was trying to use it in a 64 bit application. I see the following in the diagnostics window in simulink:

C:\Users\ops\dll_run\multiply_dll_2_cn_rtw>call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\VCVARSALL.BAT " x86

---

** Visual Studio 2017 Developer Command Prompt v15.9.7 
** Copyright (c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation

---

[vcvarsall.bat] Environment initialized for: 'x86'

Which makes me think that the DLL is 32 bit. I have tried changing the compiler to MinGW64 but still get the same issue.

Comment: It's almost certainly a compiler set-up issue, not directly a Simulink issue. What version of MATLAB are you using? What target are you using to generate the dll? If using the ERT Shared Library target, have you tried the [example](https://www.mathworks.com/help/ecoder/ug/creating-and-using-host-based-shared-libraries.html) to see if it works?

Comment: The matlab version is 2018b. The target is cn.tlc. I am trying to generate a DLL that can be used in Vector CANoe.

Comment: I'd still recommend trying the standard ERT Shared Library target example.  If it works, then the problem lies in the set-up for the cn.tlc target rather than Simulink Coder in general or MSVC.